# How editing chapter number at Fancy Page?

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

I am very interesting about fancy page and i have minimal working answers dan the result :

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype,soul,filecontents}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{lettrine,caption,multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,soul}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[listings,theorems]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
% \def\rmdefault{bch} % not scaled
% \def\ttdefault{blg}
\usepackage{xcolor,filecontents,ragged2e}
\definecolor{theblue} {rgb}{0.02,0.04,0.48}
\definecolor{thered}  {rgb}{0.65,0.04,0.07}
\definecolor{thegreen}{rgb}{0.06,0.44,0.08}
\definecolor{thegrey} {gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{theshade}{gray}{0.94}
\definecolor{theframe}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand\lorem{Fusce adipiscing justo nec ante. Nullam in enim.
 Pellentesque felis orci, sagittis ac, malesuada et, facilisis in,
 ligula. Nunc non magna sit amet mi aliquam dictum. In mi. Curabitur
 sollicitudin justo sed quam et quadd. \par}

\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX, [primitive]TeX}

% Emphasis
\newcommand\emphasis[2][thered]{\lstset{emph={newcommand,def,gdef,#2},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%

\lstset{language={[LaTeX]TeX},
      escapeinside={{(*@}{@*)}},
       numbers=left, gobble=0,
       stepnumber=1,numbersep=5pt,
       numberstyle={\footnotesize\color{gray}},firstnumber=last,
       breaklines=true,
       framesep=5pt,
       basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
       showstringspaces=false,
     % keywordstyle=\ttfamily\textcolor{thegreen},
      stringstyle=\color{orange},
      commentstyle=\color{black},
      rulecolor=\color{theshade},
      breakatwhitespace=true,
     showspaces=false,  % shows spacing symbol
      xleftmargin=0pt,
      xrightmargin=5pt,
      aboveskip=3pt plus1pt minus1pt, % compact the code looks ugly in type
      belowskip=7pt plus1pt minus1pt,  % user responsible to insert any skips
      backgroundcolor=\color{theshade}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{chapterx.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{chapters}[2012/04/07 v0.1 Typesetting chapters]
\newcommand\HUGE{\@setfontsize\Huge{38}{47}}
\newcommand\HHUGE{\@setfontsize\HHUGE{58}{67}}


\newenvironment{summary}
               {\list{}{\listparindent0pt %
                        \itemindent\listparindent
                        \leftmargin0pt
                        \rightmargin\leftmargin
                        \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax\itshape}
               {\endlist}

% helper macros
\gdef\thinrule{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\gdef\mediumrule{\rule{\textwidth}{0.8pt}}
%% broad positions
\newif\if@left
\newif\if@right
\newif\if@center
\@leftfalse
\@rightfalse
\@centerfalse
% newifs for number position
\newif\if@lefttitle
\newif\if@righttitle
\newif\if@leftname
\newif\if@rightname
\newif\if@chapterspaceout\@chapterspaceoutfalse
\newif\if@titlespaceout\@chapterspaceoutfalse

%\section{Libraries}

\def\cx@optionlist{}


\def\cx@optionlist{}

\def\cxuselibrary#1{\cxset{library/.cd,#1}}
%
% The library is added by inputting the file and setting the path accordingly.
\def\cx@add@library#1#2{%
  \cxset{library/#1/.code={\@ifundefined{cxlibrary@#1@loaded}{\input #2}{}}}%
  \DeclareOption{#1}{\edef\cx@optionlist{\cx@optionlist,#1}}%
}

\def\thickrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 3pt \hfill \kern \z@}


% Define a family for chapter styling keys
\pgfkeys{/chapter/.is family}



\def\cxset{\pgfqkeys{/chapter}} %Notice this is pgf q keys
% spent half the evening to debug it;)Aarg!!!
% We define keys for all major components
\cxset{%
  name/.code={\gdef\chaptername{#1}},
  color/.store in=\color@cx,
  color/.default=black,
  chapter font-family/.store in=\chapterfontfamily@cx,
  chapter font-weight/.store in=\chapterfontweight@cx,
  chapter font-size/.store in=\chapterfontsize@cx,
  chapter color/.store in=\chaptercolor@cx,
  chapter before/.store in=\chapterbefore@cx,
  chapter after/.store in=\chapterafter@cx,
  chapter spaceout/.is choice,
  chapter spaceout/soul/.code={\@chapterspaceouttrue},
  chapter spaceout/none/.code={\@chapterspaceoutfalse},
  % title keys
  title font-family/.store in=\titlefontfamily@cx,
  title font-family/.default=\rmfamily,
  title font-weight/.store in=\titlefontweight@cx,
  title font-size/.store in=\titlefontsize@cx,
  title font-color/.store in=\titlefontcolor@cx,
  title spaceout/.is choice,
  title spaceout/soul/.code={\@titlespaceouttrue},
  title spaceout/none/.code={\@titlespaceoutfalse},
  title font/.style={title font-family=#1},
  title before/.store in=\titlebefore@cx,
  title after/.store in=\titleafter@cx,
  title beforeskip/.store in=\titlebeforeskip@cx,
  title afterskip/.store in=\titleafterskip@cx,
  position/.is choice,
  position/left/.code={\@lefttrue},
  position/right/.code={\@righttrue},
  position/center/.code={\@centertrue},
% numbering options that are required
  numbering/.is choice,
% better to rename thechapter?
  numbering/roman/.code={\gdef\thechapter{\@roman\c@chapter}},
  numbering/Roman/.code={\gdef\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}},
  numbering/arabic/.code={\gdef\thechapter{\@arabic\c@chapter}},
  numbering/none/.code={\gdef\thechapter{}},
  number dot/.store in=\numberpunctuation@cx,
  number position/.is choice,
  number position/leftname/.code={\@leftnametrue\@rightnamefalse},
  number position/rightname/.code={\@rightnametrue\@leftnamefalse},
  number position/absolute/.code={},
  number position/righttitle/.code={\@righttitletrue},
  number position/lefttitle/.code={\@lefttitletrue},
  number after/.store in=\numberafter@cx,
  number before/.store in=\numberbefore@cx,
  number color/.store in=\numbercolor@cx,
  number font-size/.store in=\numberfontsize@cx,
  number font-family/.store in=\numberfontfamily@cx,
  number font-weight/.store in=\numberfontweight@cx,
% headers and footers
  header style/.store in=\headerstyle@cx,
% general draft rules
  rule /.is choice,
  rule on/.code={\gdef\rulewidth@cx{0.4pt}},
  rule off/.code={\gdef\rulewidth@cx{0pt}},
}

\cxset{%
  color=blue,
  position=center,
  name=chapteris,
  title font-family=\rmfamily,
  title font-weight=\bfseries,
  title font-size=\Huge,
  title font-color=\color{olive},
  numbering=arabic,
  number dot=,
  chapter font-family=\sffamily,
  chapter font-weight=\bfseries,
  chapter font-size=\Large,
  chapter color=gray,
  chapter before={\leavevmode\par\hfill},%need to correct for 0pt
  chapter after=\hfill\hfill,
  number position=rightname,
  number color=\color{gray},
  number after=\hspace{20pt},
  number before=\hspace*{20pt},
  number font-size=\huge,
  number font-family=\sffamily,
  number font-weight=\bfseries,
  number before=,
  number after=,
  title before=,
  title after=,
  title afterskip={\vskip50pt},
  title beforeskip={\vskip10pt},
  header style=plain,
}

\gdef\setdefaults{%
\cxset{%
name=CHAPTER,
title font-family=\rmfamily,
title font-weight=\bfseries,
title font-size=\Huge,
title font-color=\color{purple},
numbering=arabic,
number dot=,
number before=,
number after=,
chapter font-family=\sffamily,
chapter font-weight=\bfseries,
chapter font-size=\large,
chapter spaceout=soul,
chapter color=gray,
chapter before={},%need to correct for 0pt
chapter after=,
number position=rightname,
number color=\color{gray},
number after=\hspace{20pt},
number before=\space,
number font-size=\large,
number font-family=\sffamily,
number font-weight=\bfseries,
title before=,
title after=,
title afterskip={\vskip24pt},
title beforeskip={\vskip10pt},
title font=\rmfamily,
header style=plain,
}
}

% The |\@makechapterhead| is used by LaTeX to typeset the
% Chapter heading. This is a rewrite in order to make it
% more flexible and use the keys.

\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[2][]{%
% macro for typesetting the chapter number
  \def\printnumber{%
    \numberbefore@cx
      {%
      \numbercolor@cx
      \numberfontsize@cx
      \numberfontfamily@cx
      \numberfontweight@cx
      \thechapter
      \numberpunctuation@cx
      }
      \numberafter@cx
  }%
% macro for typesetting the chapter name
  \def\printchaptername{%
    {
    \chapterfontfamily@cx
    \chapterfontsize@cx
    \chapterfontweight@cx
    \color{\chaptercolor@cx}
% Check if the chapter name is spaced out and use the
% soul package. TODO add values for soul parameters
% as a style feature.
    \if@chapterspaceout
     \expandafter\so\expandafter{\chaptername}
    \else
      \@chapapp\space
    \fi
    }%
  }%
% set all keys
    {%
    \parindent0pt
    \normalfont%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne%
      \if@mainmatter%
 % we start displaying  the names and any preambles such
 % as images
 % print chapter name
         \chapterbefore@cx%
         \if@leftname
            \printnumber
         \fi%
         \printchaptername
         \if@rightname
            \printnumber
         \fi%
         \chapterafter@cx
      \fi%
    \fi%
     %chapter title
    \interlinepenalty\@M%
% if the number is before the title
% if the number prints together with the title they
% are considered as one indivisible part.
     \titlebeforeskip@cx%
     \if@lefttitle%
       \beforenumber@cx%
       \counterdisplay\c@chapter\afternumber@cx%
     \fi
% Display title
      \titlefontfamily@cx
      \titlefontweight@cx
      \titlefontsize@cx
      \titlefontcolor@cx
      \selectfont
      \titlebefore@cx%
      \if@titlespaceout
         \so{#2}%
      \else
         #2
      \fi%
      \titleafter@cx
    \if@righttitle%
      \afternumber@cx
      \counterdisplay\c@chapter\afternumber@cx%
    \fi
    \par\nobreak%
% skip after title
    \titleafterskip@cx
% headers
    \thispagestyle{\headerstyle@cx}
}}


%% Special Chapter command
\newcommand\specialchapter@cx[2][]{%
\cxset{image/.store in=\image@cx,
       image caption/.store in=\caption@cx}
\cxset{#1}
\vbox to 0pt{\color{blue}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}\par\vskip-1.4pt
\rule{0.4pt}{\textheight}\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}}

\vbox to 0pt{\parbox[b]{4.7cm}{%
\raggedright

\leftskip1.5cm
\caption@cx\par
 \expandafter\rule{\rulewidth@cx}{5.8cm}
}\parbox[b]{0.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=0.5cm,height=9.15cm]{shadow2}}\includegraphics{\image@cx}\par}

\vspace{8.2cm}
\hspace*{-3.51cm}\hbox to 0pt{\hspace*{1.01cm}\includegraphics[width=7.7cm,height=3.8cm]{shadow4}
\hspace*{-2.7cm}\sffamily\color{\numbercolor@cx}\HHUGE \raise30pt\hbox{4}%
\hspace{1.5cm}\raise0.5pt\hbox{\includegraphics{shadow5}\includegraphics{shadow4}}
}

%% Title name
\parbox[b]{0.45\textwidth}{%
  \titlefontsize@cx
  \titlefontweight@cx
  \titlefontfamily@cx
  \leftskip0.5em \color{\titlefontcolor@cx}
  #2
}
%% Concepts
}

\newenvironment{specialchapter}[2][]{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \specialchapter@cx[#1]{#2}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
    \raggedright
}{\end{minipage}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{chapterx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\author{Y Lazarides}
\title{\parindent0pt A New Approach in\\ Styling Chapters}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\setdefaults

\cxset{
 name={CHAPTER CONCEPT},
 numbering=none,
 number font-size=,
 number font-family=,
 number font-weight=,
 number color=white,
 chapter color=theblue,
 chapter font-family=\sffamily,
 chapter font-size=\large,
 chapter font-weight=\bfseries,
 title font-family=\sffamily,
 title font-color=theblue,
 rule off,
}

\begin{specialchapter}[
     image=catcute,%genetics-dogs,
     image caption={Labrador retriever\\
         puppies expressing\\
         brown (chocolate),\\
         golden (yellow),\\
         and black\\
         coat colors,\\
         traits controlled\\
         by two gene pairs.}]%
{Extensions\\ of Mendelian\\ Genetics}
\end{specialchapter}




\end{document}
```

and The Result : 
[image: The Result]
And i have a problem about setting table of contents and chapter name, like this  picture 
[image: Replace and Add Chapter]

Comment: This is still just too much. Focus your attention on a single part of the document (say, the ToC). Then create a [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that *is* minimal, not like yours is at the moment. It will help the community digest the problem and provide you with answers much quicker.

Comment: There are too many different questions here.  Please ask one question at a time.  See our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: I'm  sorry , i'm bad in english , i have problem about add chapter to TOC

Comment: Your rewritten code for chapters contains none of the original material incrementing the counters nor adding contents line.  Cf. the code in `book.cls`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann , i tried my code and succesfull... you can see more detail my code can downloaded at   
http://www.ziddu.com/download/22416580/fancypage.rar.html

Comment: Please post code that (a) compiles to give the problematic output and (b) contains only what is essential.